# Cannot get sed to work with a variable and quotes

Tags: sed

I am about to write a shell script to replace this line:

```
exec "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}
```

with:

```
exec qemu-arm -L /mnt/c/git/build/linux_arm7/build_arm7/sysroot "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}
```

in a file.
`/mnt/c/git/build/linux_arm7/build_arm7` is now in a variable called `BUILD_DIRECTORY`.
Whatever I tried (quotes, different separators) I always end up with the variable instead of the replacement.
For example I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed_test()
{
    sed -i 's|exec "\$progdir\/\$program" \${1+"\$@"}|exec qemu-arm -L ${BUILD_DIRECTORY}\/sysroot "\$progdir\/\$program" \${1+"\$@"}|g' ${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/file
}
```

and got this in the file:

```
exec qemu-arm -L ${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/sysroot "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- quote prevent expansion of `${BUILD_DIRECTORY}` variable
- final `g` is not needed
- you escape way to much

If there is no space in BUILD_DIRECTORY variable, use

```
sed -i 's|exec "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}|exec qemu-arm -L '${BUILD_DIRECTORY}'/sysroot "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}|'  ${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/file
```

note single quote around `${BUILD_DIRECTORY}`

in case of space in BUILD_DIRECTORY (let say `linux arm7`), use a relay string (command splited)

```
sed -e 's|exec "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}|exec qemu-arm -L BUILD_DIRECTORY/sysroot "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}|'  
   -e "s|BUILD_DIRECTORY|${BUILD_DIRECTORY}|" 
   "${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/file"
```

yielding

```
exec qemu-arm -L /mnt/c/git/build/linux arm7/build_arm7/sysroot "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}
```

Comment: Your *problem with space* that you're trying to work around with the two steps is only because you forgot to double quote the `${BUILD_DIRECTORY}` expansions in the first one (so did the OP), and the problem is not so much with space but with characters of `$IFS` (and space is in the default value of `$IFS`). But even then, if space or any character special in the sh syntax, is in `$BUILD_DIRECTORY`, the resulting text, if we consider that it's obviously shell code would be incorrect.

Comment: I didn't check all of it, so I'm not sure what the escaping way too much refers to, but the fact that they escaped the `$` signs in the sed question isn't that obviously wrong. `$` is special in regexes in that it anchors to the end of the string. Now, it looks like it does work here like that _in BRE_, but not in ERE (weirdly enough). But as far as I read the spec, escaping it anyway in either should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` and `perl`:

```
SRC='exec "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}' \
  DST='exec qemu-arm -L '${(qq)BUILD_DIRECTORY}' "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}' \
  perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{SRC}\E/$ENV{DST}/g' -- "$BUILD_DIRECTORY/file"
```

Since it's obviously Bourne-like shell code you're editing, you'll want to make sure the result is valid shell code. So you'll want the contents of the `$BUILD_DIRECTORY` variable inserted in a way that when parsed by `sh` results in that value passed to `qemu-arm` as one argument even if it contains characters that are otherwise special in the syntax of the shell such as `;`, `?`, `'`, space...

Best for that is to express it single-quoted which is the safest mode of quoting in `sh`, and if the variable contains single quote characters, insert them as `\'` outside of the single quotes for instance. That's what the `qq` parameter expansion flag does in `zsh`. For instance, it turns:

- The empty string into `''`
- `a;b` into `'a;b'`
- `a'b` into `'a'\''b'`

Expanding the value of `$BUID_DIRECTORY` inside the code passed to `sed` means you're introducing code (`sed` code) injection vulnerabilities, unless you escape the characters that are special in that context. Also note that `-i` (which some `sed` implementations have copied from `perl`) is not standard.

Using `perl` instead means that:

- you can use `-i` portably
- you don't need to escape the regexp operator in the `$SRC` as we can use `\Q`/`\E` for that.
- you don't need to escape the replacement either.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go in using variables to interpolate sed code is to first escape the shell veriable contents depending on whether it is being used om LHS or RHS of `s///` command.

In your scenario the build variable will be placed on the rhs. So we will need to escape the `& \ and :` characters since in the actual sed code we use `s:::` as delimiters. Plus should the build variable be multiline we escape the newlines within it also. And since the variable will be enrobed in single quotes we need to also change all single quote to `'\''` just in case build variable had single quotes in it.

```
BUILD_DIRECTORY='/mnt/c/git/build/linux_arm7/build_arm7'

BUILD_DIRECTORY_rhs=$(printf '%s\n' "${BUILD_DIRECTORY}" |
sed \
  -e 's/[\&:]/\\&/g'    \
  -e 's/'\''/&\\\\&&/g' \
  -e '$!s/$/\\/')

sed -i -e 's:^exec \("$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}\)$:'"exec qemu-arm -L '${BUILD_DIRECTORY_rhs}/sysroot' \\1:"  -- "${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/file"
```

This outputs:

```
exec qemu-arm -L '/mnt/c/git/build/linux_arm7/build_arm7/sysroot' "$progdir/$program" ${1+"$@"}
```